# Giving discount for certain cards in Apple pay

Tags: ios, applepay

I have a requirement where I need to give certain discount on some family of credit card in my iOS app. Is their a way to do this in Apple Pay?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only

Comment: @musefan This involves programming application to support apple pay discount on certain cards in apps

Comment: What have you tried? - Have you looked at the [PassKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit) Documentation?

Comment: @Wez I have looked at API's. But I can't see any way to do it. So I think this is a common scenario, so if any one else have come across this problem than he he suggest me some work around

Comment: Looks like you want to use `PKPaymentNetwork` [from the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentnetwork)